# LINQ-to-Objects - What's wrong with this simple Composite Key grouping?

Tags: linq-to-objects

Ok guys... first time posting a question on here.  I'm trying to demo a couple features of LINQ and have hit a snag. The following query isn't performing as expected:

```
Dim peopleByAgeAndName = _
    From p In (New PeopleRepository).GetAll
    Group By key = New With {p.Age, p.Name} Into Group
    Select Group
```

Here is the very simple PeopleRepository:

```
Public Class PeopleRepository
     Public Function GetAll() As List(Of Person)
        Dim people As New List(Of Person)
        people.Add(New Person With {.Name = "Test Name #1", .Age = 33})
        people.Add(New Person With {.Name = "Test Name #1", .Age = 33})
        people.Add(New Person With {.Name = "Test Name #2", .Age = 0})
        people.Add(New Person With {.Name = "Test Name #3", .Age = 0})
        people.Add(New Person With {.Name = "Test Name #4", .Age = 0})
        people.Add(New Person With {.Name = "Test Name #5", .Age = 35})
        people.Add(New Person With {.Name = "Test Name #1", .Age = 39})
        Return people
    End Function
End Class
```

And here is the even simpler Person class:

```
Public Class Person
    Property Name As String
    Property Age As Integer
End Class
```

Obviously this is all code setup for testing purposes.  After executing the `peopleByAgeAndName` query, I expect to get 6 groups.  Each containing one Person object except the group corresponding to "Test Name #1" and an age of 33.  No matter what I do, though, I get 7 groups of one element each.

Any thoughts?  I'm wondering if this is normal for LINQ-to-Objects?  Again, it's all testing code.  I'm just trying to better understand how this works.  It was my understanding that when using an anonymous object as the key, it should do a property-by-property comparison for the groups.  I SHOULD be getting 6 groups, not 7.

Thanks!

Update -

For the record, the query rewritten in C# performs exactly as I expect:

```
 var peopleByAgeAndName =
        from p in peopleRepository.GetAll()
        group p by new {p.Age, p.Name}  into g 
        select g;
```

I get 6 groups instead of 7.  I also confirmed that the group key is not available in VB but is in C#.  Kinda weird.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for my contrived situation... in Visual Basic, you have to add the "Key" attribute to any property in an Anonymous Type that can be used to determine uniqueness:

```
Dim peopleByAgeAndName = _
    From p In (New PeopleRepository).GetAll
    Group p By k = New With {Key p.Age, Key p.Name} Into g = Group
    Select g
```

Works like a charm now!  Thanks for your advice guys!

Comment: I found that in order to reference the group columns, I had to reference k, not g

Answer (score 0):

You need an IEqualityComparer that'll give you distinct objects based on Ids perhaps.

Comment: I understand I would need to do that if I were using custom types as the criteria in my composite key, but since I'm using an anonymous type of String, Integer... I don't think I should have to implement an IEqualityCOmparer.  It shouldn't be trying to compare Person objects at all.  Just the keys.

Answer (score 0):

The group key is what you want to group by. You're mixing up group and select:

```
var grp=from p in persons
        group p by p.Name into g
        select new {g.Key, Ages=g};
```

Then you'd iterate over it like this:

```
foreach(var name in grp)
{
  Console.WriteLine(name.Key);

  foreach(var age in name)
    Console.WriteLine("  "+age.Age);
}
```

This is very simplistic though, a better grouping would be like:

```
var grp=from p in persons
        group p by p.Name into g
        select new {Name=g.Key, Ages=from a in g
                                     select a.Age};
```

Comment: I'm looking at your recommendation but I don't think the result will do what I'm looking to do. I understand your idea of grouping on one of the criteria and projecting into another object the subitems... but what if I have 4 or 5 or 6 criteria I want to group by?  I want it to be grouped on the distinct key (combination of all key values)... with my data above, I want the result to be an IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of Person)) objects and it should contain 6 items, with the first one containing 2 items, and the rest containing 1 item each.

Comment: Also, ne problemn I'm running into is that there is no Group.Key in LINQ for VB.Net.  I haven't found a way to get the key for each group yet. Maybe the syntax is different, but group.key doesn't exist.